# RDP not respecting client's desktop scale factor

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

We upgraded our laptops and their resolution went from the old laptops' 1366 x 768 to 1920 x 1080 and this is causing our one Remote Desktop server to scale everything small so it's hard to see. I tried adding the "desktopscalefactor:i:" value in the RDP file, but RDP completely ignores this.

And I can't change the scale settings inside the remote session because it won't let you:
[image: 263513-image.png]

Client Computer Display Settings:
[image: 263514-client-display-settings.png]

Here's the RDP file with my values: https://pastebin.com/2dxVJz96

It's important I make the scale larger for our employees to see the text and windows easily. :)

Comment: What values did you try for `desktopscalefactor:i:value`?

Comment: @user2871239 I tried 125 and 150 (125%, 150%, respectively)

Comment: I'm sure I went through similar issues and had to apply a registry key to the remote server.  I just tried setting the value to 0 to undo the fix so I could test it and now I can't remote onto it at all!  I'm going to have to wait to get someone to give it a kick tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving up and just spinning up a WS2016 VM for users to remote into and then run the application over the network.